# Display data into text box

Tags: php

I'm new in working on PHP. My little project works on display first and last name of student, according to h/is/er id.
index page should have 3 text box:

- student id
- first name
- last name

when inserting student id in the first text box and press enter key, related information must appear in the other two boxes(first and last name).

Code in validation.php:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_sars') or die(mysqli_error());

$student_no = $_GET['student_no'];
$query = "SELECT student_no,firstname,lastname FROM student WHERE student_no = '$student_no'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)<1) {
  echo "<span class='green'>Available</span>";
}
else{
  $followingdata = $result->fetch_assoc();
  echo $followingdata["firstname"].'<br />';
  echo $followingdata["lastname"].'<br />';
}
```

index.html  contains ajax script and text boxes:

```
 </br><input type="text" name="student_no" id="student_no" placeholder="Enter student #"></div></br>

<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" >

    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" >
```

Comment: You are mixing the *procedural* and *object* style of mysqli, cannot be done. Either you connect with `mysqli_connect()` or create an object of `mysqli` and use `$con->query()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach:  Since the page reloads when you submit the form, you could simply populate the values of the inputs when you load the page by storing your values rather than echo-ing them:

PHP:

```
$first = $followingdata["firstname"];
$last = $followingdata["lastname"];
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<? echo $first ?>">
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<? echo $last ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

php

```
$followingdata = $result->fetch_assoc();
$first_name = $followingdata["firstname"];
$last_name = $followingdata["lastname"];

echo json_encode(array(
    'first' = $first_name,
    'last' = $last_name,
));
```

your ajax succeed callback function

```
function (data) {
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if (obj) {
        var first = obj.first;
        var last = obj.last;
        document.getElementById('firstname').value = first;
        document.getElementById('lastname').value = last;
    }
}
```

html

```
<input type="text" name="student_no" id="student_no" placeholder="Enter student #"></div>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" >
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" >
```

Comment: Thank you Dobe Lee . .working fine

'first' => $first_name,
    'last' => $last_name,